# how to call a function in c++

Tags: c++, function

Good morning community. I do have this header file, which is called SimVehicleParticular

```
enter code here
#ifndef _simVehicleParticular_h_
#define _simVehicleParticular_h_

#include "A2BehavioralModelUtil.h"
#include "A2SimVehicle.h"

class A2BEHAVIORALEXPORT simVehicleParticular: public A2SimVehicle
{
 private:
 float newAttribute;

public:
simVehicleParticular ( void *handlerVehicle, unsigned short idhandler,bool  isFictitiousVeh );
~ simVehicleParticular ();
const float getnewAttribute() const;
void setnewAttribute ( float avalue);
};

#endif
```

I also have another header which is called A2SimVehicle and a part of it comprises:

```
enter code here
#ifndef _A2SimVehicle_h_
#define _A2SimVehicle_h_

#include "A2BehavioralModelUtil.h"

typedef A2BEHAVIORALEXPORT struct yieldInfo{
double distance2ConfVehiclePrio;
double distance2ConfVehicleGiveWay;
bool isVehiclePrioWithinVisibility;
bool isVehiclePrioRealAndReachingConflict;
bool isVehicleGiveWayComingNext;
bool isVehiclePrioAfectedByStop;
bool isVehiclePrioAfectedByYellowBox;
bool isVehiclePrioAfectedByGiveWay;
bool isVehiclePrioPrioritaryBasedOnWaitingTime;
bool isVehiclePrioComingNext;
bool isVehiclePrioLeaderOfVehicleGiveWay;
double passingTimeVehiclePrio;
double leavingTimeVehiclePrio;
double passingTimeVehicleGiveWay;
double leavingTimeVehicleGiveWay;
double safetyMargin;
} yieldInfo;


enter code here
class A2BEHAVIORALEXPORT A2SimVehicle
{
public:
A2SimVehicle( void *handlerVehicle, unsigned short idhandler, bool isFictitiousVeh );
virtual ~A2SimVehicle();

/*!
    Internal function to be used only by the microsimulator
*/
void setHandlerVehicle( void *handlerVehicle );
void * getHandlerVehicle() {return handlerVehicle;};
```

One of it's member's is :

```
enter code here
A2SimVehicle * getRealLeader(double &Shift) const;
```

Now as far as the source file is concerned, I want to call a function whih goes like this :

```
enter code here
double behavioralModelParticular::getIDMDeceleration(simVehicleParticular *vehicle, simVehicleParticular *leader)
 {
//int id = vehicle->getId();
//int idl = leader->getId();

double Shift;
Shift = 0;
double  ShiftLeader;
ShiftLeader = 0;
simVehicleParticular *tempVeh;
int idT;
double a = vehicle->getAcceleration();
double b = vehicle->getDeceleration();
double VelAnterior, PosAnterior, VelAnteriorLeader, PosAnteriorLeader;
double GapAnterior = vehicle->getGap(Shift, leader, ShiftLeader, PosAnterior, VelAnterior, PosAnteriorLeader, VelAnteriorLeader);
double DesiredGap = getIDMMinimumGap(vehicle, leader, VelAnterior, VelAnteriorLeader, GapAnterior);
double X = VelAnterior / vehicle->getFreeFlowSpeed();
double acceleration = max(b, a*(1 - pow(X, 4) - (DesiredGap / GapAnterior)*(DesiredGap / GapAnterior)));
return acceleration;
}
```

My question is , that I want to call this function like this :

```
double accelcurrent = getIDMDeceleration((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle, (A2SimVehicle *)vehicle->getRealLeader(temp));
```

However, when I put :

```
(A2SimVehicle *)vehicle->getRealLeader(temp))
```

a warning appears which says :

error:argument of type "A2SimVehicle" is incompatible with parameter of type 
"SimVehicleParticular".

Can you tell me how to call this function correctly combining both the headers I described above? Any help whatsover would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you!

I altered the function:

```
double behavioralModelParticular::getIDMDeceleration(simVehicleParticular*vehicle, A2SimVehicle*leader). However , now a line inside the function doesn't reognize the leader.


double DesiredGap = getIDMMinimumGap(vehicle, leader, VelAnterior, VelAnteriorLeader, GapAnterior);
```

I also left the :

```
double accelcurrent = getIDMDeceleration((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle, (A2SimVehicle *)vehicle->getRealLeader(temp));  the same. What happens now?
```

Comment: What's the point of casting result of `getRealLeader` to `A2SimVehicle *`, when that's already what the function returns? Even more when the parameter is `simVehicleParticular *` -- a pointer to a class derived from `A2SimVehicle`. You need to downcast the result from `getRealLeader`.

Comment: A `simVehicleParticular` is a kind of `A2SimVehicle`, as it derives from that class. The other way round doesn't have to be true.

Comment: @DanMašek , can you explain to me what do you mean by downcasting the result from getRealLeader.

Comment: @bazooka I'm pretty certain this has been explained countless times. A simple search will do.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of your function is:

```
double behavioralModelParticular::getIDMDeceleration(simVehicleParticular *vehicle, simVehicleParticular *leader)
```

Which says that the `leader` parameter is of type pointer to `simVehicleParticular` type.

When you call the function

```
double accelcurrent = getIDMDeceleration((simVehicleParticular *)vehicle, (A2SimVehicle *)vehicle->getRealLeader(temp));
```

you give it a temporary variable that is the result of the call `vehicle->getRealLeader(temp)` and then you typecast it to the type of pointer to `A2SimVehicle`! So the function `getIDMDeceleration()` gets a type `A2SimVehicle*`. And the compiler is telling you that this type is not compatible with `simVehicleParticular*`.

You will have to either make the function `getRealLeader()` to return a `simVehicleParticular*` or make the function `getIDMDeceleration()` accept the leader as the type of `A2SimVehicle*`.

```
double behavioralModelParticular::getIDMDeceleration(simVehicleParticular* vehicle, A2SimVehicle* leader)
```

or

```
simVehicleParticular* getRealLeader(double &Shift) const;
```